# Dropbox Datastore Global Sync Observer Architecture on iOS

Tags: ios7, synchronization, dropbox-api

In my iOS app, there are several different view controllers each with its own data. I want to have a central place in my app where I have an observer of any changes on the Datastore server. This central place would then notify various other parts of the app to update with the latest data. The reason I'm doing it this way is because I'm syncing the datastore to a local SQLite database.

I've tried adding an observer to a view controller like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.store addObserver:self block:^() {
  if(weakSelf.store.status & DBDatastoreIncoming) {
    NSDictionary *changes = [weakSelf.store sync:nil];
    // Handle the updated data
    NSLog(@"Changes: %@",changes);
  }
}];
```

After making data changes on another device, this observer doesn't fire.

If a central sync observer isn't possible, does that mean I have to add an observer to every single view controller that has syncable data?

Comment: Perhaps the view controller where you register the observer is no longer around when the changes happen? Hard to tell from just this code.

Comment: Good question. I'm using a hamburger menu, and the menu view controller is where this observer is. I'm fairly new to Obj-C, but it seems the menu is always around since it can be viewed/opened from any other view controller.

Comment: My guess would still be that the view controller is no longer around when the observer should be called. Perhaps you can instrument the view controller's lifecycle and see when it's being destroyed.